# How to keep mute button available during call

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, microphone

I use my iPhone for conference calls regularly, with a Bluetooth headset/microphone. Often I keep my mic muted except for when I speak.

It is awkward that when I want to speak, I need to wake-up and unlock my phone, before pressing the mute button.

Is there a way to make my phone stay awake during calls, without changing the sleep/lock settings generally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swipe right at the unlock screen during an active call and the controls are displayed. There's no need to unlock the phone to access the mute.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that out. If it works, I'll upvote and accept. It would be even nicer to be able to touch the mute button directly, but looks like that won't be an option.

Comment: I've been playing with it a little and it's not totally reliable. I think it works if you have the call open when the phone locks, but not if you've switched to another application.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in iOS 10; it brings up the camera, instead. The [answer by m1.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251982/61389) works.

Answer (score 20):

In iOS10 you can just tap the number + call duration in the lock screen and it'll bring up the phone controls.

Comment: This works for me but is really not intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a really easy way. If your phone is locked, simply click the phone number/contact name and it quick links you to the screen with the mute button on.

Like another poster, I've found when you unlock the phone normally, it links you to the last app, and then you've got to app switch to go to the phone and then mute, so it's unlock->app->switch->mute.

The method above is click->mute.

It's not perfect, but it's meant I don't have to have an uncomfortable 5 second pause when someone wants to speak to me and I've muted my sound.

Comment: Thanks. I no longer use an iPhone, so I can't reasonably determine if your answer is useful -- I'll leaving any voting to others.

Comment: This is correct, though it's the same solution as [m1.'s answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251982/61389).

Answer (score 0):

To keep it awake: try blocking the ambient light sensor with your hand or an object, so iPhone thinks you're holding it against your face. Then remove the obstruction to awaken the phone.

This incurs a delay to awaken but might be worth a try.

Personally I solved this by simply getting a Jawbone earpiece. They feature excellent built-in noise cancellation technology, so when I'm not speaking, even with the AC on full blast in my car, there's just a flatline of silence when I'm not speaking.

Comment: Was worth a try, but didn't work. Might work for someone else ...

Answer (score -1):

Swipe right on lock screen works as mentioned in above post. If you unlock the screen with your fingerprint already you will see a green bar of the phone talk on top - swipe right on the top green bar also bring up the button to mute / unmute.